# Help identifying the species or group for this ultrasonic vocalization (a rat?)

Tags: terrestrial, species-identification, call-identification

I am reviewing some audio recorded with an Audiomoth a couple of weeks ago in Bolivia (south America). The target group was bats, but I found these vocalizations which are unlikely for a bat due to the duration.

[image: Spectrogram for unknown species call, between 26 kHz - 34 kHz]

The lowest frequency is approximately 26.7 kHz, the highest is 34 kHz, and the duration is almost 1 second. There are also a few calls that last around 350 ms. My recording lasted 5 minutes and the calls were emitted for most of the 5 minute period.

Since I am in the city, I thought that this could be a rodent. The most similar vocalizations I found are for rats, although the call is categorized as a 22 kHz call and has a shorter duration https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3425/11/4/459 .

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: There are for sure people with more expertise on this topic out there.

For, me it looks like a Black Rat. Compared with the appendix of the work of Newson et al. 2020, I would go with Black Rat. That corresponds with your guess and the environment.
You can check out the work [here](https://www.bto.org/our-science/publications/peer-reviewed-papers/acoustic-identification-small-terrestrial-mammals), its worthwile. The Appendix gives some examples, found at the bottom of the page.

Cheers,
Dominik